# tf.matmul to find theta that minimizes the cost function

Tags: python, matrix, tensorflow

I am using TensorFlow to calculate the value of theta that minimizes the cost function  where theta = Inverse of(xT . X) . xT . y

I am following along the tutorial in https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/09_up_and_running_with_tensorflow.ipynb

```
booktheta = tf.matmul(tf.matmul(tf.matrix_inverse(tf.matmul(XT,X)),XT),y)

mytheta = tf.matmul(tf.matrix_inverse(tf.matmul(XT,X)),tf.matmul(XT,y))

with tf.Session() as sess:
   book_tvalue= booktheta.eval()
   print(book_tvalue)

[[ -3.74651413e+01]
[  4.35734153e-01]
[  9.33829229e-03]
[ -1.06622010e-01]
[  6.44106984e-01]
[ -4.25131839e-06]
[ -3.77322501e-03]
[ -4.26648885e-01]
[ -4.40514028e-01]]


with tf.Session as sess:
   my_tvalue= mytheta.eval()
   print(my_tvalue)

  [[ -3.74218750e+01]
  [  4.35844421e-01]
  [  9.34600830e-03]
  [ -1.06735229e-01]
  [  6.44439697e-01]
  [ -4.22634184e-06]
  [ -3.77440453e-03]
  [ -4.26208496e-01]
  [ -4.40002441e-01]]
```

I am trying to understand why the two are different and if I am interpreting the way theta is being calculated accurately.

Comment: The difference between those two results looks fairly small, and could probably be explained by rounding errors in the two different methods for calculating theta.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I was wondering if it was the way I was carrying out the matrix multiplication.